# Customized email verification success page using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am generating email verification using the default Firebase function.
The default email verification success page looks like that:

[image]

I want to customize the response page after successful email verification.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You'll have to setup your own server to handle verification for that.

Comment: I think a custom email action handler should allow that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to customize the response page after successful email
> verification. Is there a way to do that?

Yes, as Frank indicated in his above comment, it is possible and the [documentation he refers to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) explains the mechanism.

As explained in this doc (and also in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096144/3371862) :-) ), you need to build a web page in which you will:

1. Get the values passed as QueryString parameters (e.g. `mode` or `oobCode`)
2. Call, from this web page, the `applyActionCode()` method of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, passing the values of these parameters to the method.
3. Upon successful verification, do something, like redirect the user to your app login page.

---

What's important to note is that you have two ways to generate the email sent to the user (which contains the link to the page described above):

**1. Rely on the default Firebase mail mechanism.** In order to customize the URL of the verification link (e.g. you want to redirect to https://www.myrapp.com/emailVerifyScreen) you need to change the base URL as shown in the below image ("Customize action URL"). Also explained here in the doc.

[image]

**2. Send the email through a Cloud Function (or through a server you own).** In this case you need to:

a/ Call the [`generateEmailVerificationLink()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#generateemailverificationlink) method of the Admin SDK, which returns a link

b/ Generate an email containing this link

c/ Send the email to the user (via an SMTP server you control or via a microservice like Mailjet or Sendgrid)

---

You may have a look at these other answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66350538/3371862
- [Flutter: Sending Email Verification code through FlutterFire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149438/flutter-sending-email-verification-code-through-flutterfire/64151927#64151927)
- [How to sign up only the users who have verified thier email addresses using the email link in Firebase javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898754/how-to-sign-up-only-the-users-who-have-verified-thier-email-addresses-using-the/60903657#60903657)